# Nhibernate 3.1 SQL-(UPDATE, INSERT) stored procedure parameter order

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to get an insert stored procedure to work on an entity mapped to a view.  The problem is the syntax is something like

```
<sql-insert>EXEC InsertNote ?,?,?</sql-insert>
<sql-update>EXEC UpdateNote ?,?,?,?</sql-update>
<sql-delete>EXEC DeleteNote ?</sql-delete>
```

I have about 1500 of these, some with over 100 fields, to generate.
is there any way to KNOW what order nhibernate will generate the parameters in (other than verifying the orm call to the sql server through profiling)?

I realize model complexity complicates this currently, but I haven't found a current answer to this issue.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are generated in the same order as the properties appear in the mapping file.

That said... this model is an huge waste of effort. Why use NHibernate if you have stored procedures for all operations? Why use stored procedures if you have NHibernate?